# JScrollPane used so I can't set bounds of other JComponents

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, setbounds

There's a simple application that uses `JScrollPane` for 2 lists and have 1 button to switch them. I want to add many more Swing elements, but I cannot move them with `object.setBounds`. Whatever I will write in this method element doesn't change its place and size.

```
package paka;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;;
public class Question extends JFrame {
    private JList leftlist,rightlist;
    private JButton movebutton;
    private JLabel pointlessLabel;
    private static String[] foods={"bacon","wings","ham","beef","more bacon"};

    public Question(){
        super("title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        leftlist=new JList(foods);
        leftlist.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        leftlist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(leftlist));
        movebutton = new JButton("Move");

        movebutton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        rightlist.setListData(leftlist.getSelectedValues());

                    }
                }
                );
        add(movebutton);

        rightlist = new JList();
        rightlist.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        rightlist.setFixedCellWidth(100);rightlist.setFixedCellHeight(15);
        rightlist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(rightlist));        

        //Okay, deleting everything below we have only two list with button that moves elements from 1st list to 2nd

        movebutton = new JButton("Click me!");
        movebutton.setBounds(700, 100, 80, 20);
        add(movebutton);

        pointlessLabel = new JLabel("I'm unbreakable");
        pointlessLabel.setBounds(500,200,100,50);
        add(pointlessLabel);



    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Question go = new Question();
        go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        go.setSize(300,200);
        go.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `so I can't set bounds of other JElements` - exactly. You should not be attempting to use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. If you use a layout manager then the scroll pane will work automatically.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use combinations of [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) (as stated by @AndrewThompson on his comment above) to achieve the same output that you have with a `null layout`.

Avoid the use of `null layout`, see: [Null layout is evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

With the code below you can have the same output you had with `setBounds()` method. I didn't added an `ActionListener` to this code, since I'm just demonstrating how to stop using `null layout` and have the same output. Yes! The second one seems shorter, that's because of `pack()` but you can still `setSize()` if you want / need an specific window size.

To add more elements below just add more `JPanel`s and add them to `pane`, I hope this helps to solve your issue, and if not, please post a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy-paste, make it short, but still shows your issue and follows above recommendations

## Important Note:

I'll bring a quote from [This answer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811555/2180785) of @MadProgrammer, because I used `prototypeCellValue` to make the `rightList`'s width shorter:

> I'd also be careful with prototypeCellValue, unless the value matches the expected length of your data, it could truncate your data when it's displayed, just need to be careful

[image]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class QuestionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        String[] foods = { "bacon", "wings", "ham", "beef", "more bacon" };
        
        JFrame frame;
        JPanel topPane, bottomPane, pane;
        JList leftList, rightList;
        JButton moveButton, clicMeButton;
        JScrollPane scroll;
        JLabel label;

        frame = new JFrame("title");
        topPane = new JPanel();
        bottomPane = new JPanel();
        pane = new JPanel();
        leftList = new JList(foods);
        rightList = new JList();
        moveButton = new JButton("Move");
        clicMeButton = new JButton("Click me!");
        label = new JLabel("I'm unbreakable");
        
        leftList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        rightList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        leftList.setPrototypeCellValue(String.format("%30s", ""));
        rightList.setPrototypeCellValue(String.format("%30s", ""));

        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        topPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        
        scroll = new JScrollPane(leftList);
        
        topPane.add(scroll);
        topPane.add(moveButton);
        
        scroll = new JScrollPane(rightList);
        topPane.add(scroll);
        
        bottomPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        bottomPane.add(clicMeButton);
        bottomPane.add(label);

        pane.add(topPane);
        pane.add(bottomPane);
        frame.add(pane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```